# Change the class of progressive bar depending on the dynamic width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a progressive bar whose width vary dynamically, so if the width is less than or equal to 50% the class of bootstrap progressive bar should be "progress-bar-warning" or else if the width is more than 50% the class of bootstrap progressive bar should be "progress-bar-success". I have checked every where but finding it difficult to get it work. please any assistance ?
This is Html Code:

customer-loan.php

```
                   <td>
                                            <span class="header-text">
                                                <div class="progress-bar 
         progress-bar-striped active progressbartextcolor" 
          id="progressbarcolorchange" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="25" 
               aria-valuemin="0" v-bind:style="{width: customerLoan.progress 
                   + '%'}" aria-valuemax="100">{{customerLoan.progress || 
           "0"}}%</div>
                                            </span>
                                        </td>
```

CustomerLoans.js

```
   var vueCustomerLoans = new Vue({
       el: "#table-records",
      data: {
    customerLoans: []
       },
         methods: {
    navigateToView: function (row) {
        document.location = "backoffice/customer-loan?id=" + 
        JSON.stringify(row.id);
       }
      }
    });
```

Comment: Since it appears you're using Vue, you should create a computed function where you check the customerLoad.progress and apply a class based on this property.

Comment: can you explain it in coding. im new to vue.js, finding it difficult to get it work

Answer (score 0):

How about getting the value of "valuenow" with "attr" ?

```
<td>
    <span class="header-text">
        <div class="progress-bar 
             progress-bar-striped active progressbartextcolor" 
             id="progressbarcolorchange" role="progressbar" aria- 
             valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" v-bind:style="{width: 
             customerLoan.progress + '%'}" aria-valuemax="100"> 
            {{customerLoan.progress || "0"}}%</div>
    </span>
</td>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var bar = $('#progressbarcolorchange').attr('valuenow');
        if (bar <= 50) {
            $('#progressbarcolorchange').addClass("progress-bar-warning");
        } else {
            $('#progressbarcolorchange').addClass("progress-bar-success");
        }
    });
</script>
```

I guess that "valuenow" is always changing, is that correct?

Comment: Is there any event for width change like resize event?

Comment: yes .change(); will check for any changes. @RohitKharat

Comment: guys any more assistance ? the above answer is not working.

Comment: is that a process that change quickly or like in days when customer are booking or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

... Firstly I would recommend you read the VueJS docs for a better understand of how computed properties work. [Computed properties](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html)

Here's what I would do in your case:

```js
window.onload = () => {
  new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data() {
      return {
        progress: 30
      }
    },
    computed: {
      cp_progress_warn: function() { 
        if(this.progress <= 50) return true;
      },
      cp_progress_success: function() { 
        if(this.progress > 50) return true;
      }  
    },
    watch: {

    },
    methods: {
    
    }
  })
}
```

```css
body { padding: 1rem; }
.progress-bar { 
      width: 100%;
      height: 20px;
    }
    .progress_bar_warning {
      background-color: red;
    }
    .progress_bar_success { 
      background-color: green;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div>
  
    Change this value &nbsp; <input type="text" v-model="progress" /><br /><br />
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active progressbartextcolor" id="progressbarcolorchange" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" v-bind:style="{ width: (progress + '%') }" v-bind:class="{ progress_bar_warning: cp_progress_warn, progress_bar_success: cp_progress_success }" aria-valuemax="100">{{progress}}%</div>
  
  </div>

</div>
```

Try that and see if it works.

Comment: Update your question with your full source code then

Comment: I've made a quick example above according to your needs. That can give you a clear view of how to solve your problem.